# Limit with sum of cube roots

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to evaluate
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\sqrt[3]{{1 \over n^4}} + \sqrt[3]{{2 \over n^4}} + \sqrt[3]{{3 \over n^4}} + \dots + \sqrt[3]{{n \over n^4}} \right)$$
I simplify the expression to

$${\sqrt[3]{1} + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \dots + \sqrt[3]{n} \over \sqrt[3]{n^4}}$$

$y_n=\sqrt[3]{n^4} \to \infty$, so we might try to use the Stolz theorem to get the limit.
$${x_{n+1}-x_n \over y_{n+1}-y_n} = {\sqrt[3]{1} + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \sqrt[3]{4} + \dots + \sqrt[3]{n+1} - \left(\sqrt[3]{1} + \sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} + \dots + \sqrt[3]{n}\right) \over \sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4}-\sqrt[3]{n^4}}={\sqrt[3]{n+1} \over \sqrt[3]{(n+1)^4} - \sqrt[3]{n^4}}$$

Whne I use the Stolz theorem, the limit seems to be $\infty$. Stolz works for $\infty$, so this would contradict the limit ${3 \over 4}$ obtained below by integration which I'm fairly confident is correct. Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Comment: I fail to understand how you would get zero in the denominator

Comment: I get the second expression using the Stolz theorem. I divide both the numerator and the denominator of this expression by $\sqrt[3]{n^4}$ and take the limit. This gives me ${0 \over 0}$.

Comment: When I graph the denominator in a graphing device, it seems like it is going to infinity. And speaking of the numerator, when $n$ goes to infinity, the numerator does not go to zero either. For clarity, I am only looking at that fraction with the cube roots and $n$ to infinity.

Comment: You're right. I've done the same and got the same result. So, in this case ${0 \over 0}$ gives $\infty$. It also means that I am missing something in my original approach based on the Stolz theorem since it would suggest that the sought limit is $\infty$ while Abdallah has shown it's ${3 \over 4}$.

Comment: I "mimicked" the series with Demos and it tends to go to Abdallah's answer though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sqrt[3]{a}-\sqrt[3]{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}+\sqrt[3]{a\,b}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}.
$$
Use it with both numerator and denominator in the expression you get from Stolz's criterium.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^\frac 13$.

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{k}{n^4})^{\frac 13}\;\;$$

is a Riemann sum and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}S_n=$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1-0}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(0+k\frac{1-0}{n})$$

$$=\int_0^1 x^\frac{1}{3}dx$$

$$=\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks. Any way to do this without the integral? I haven't properly covered integration so far, so I am guessing there has to be some other (possibly more complicated) way to do this?